# How to Hide previous month dates in current month in materialCalendarView

Tags: android, calendar, materialcardview

Material CalendarView:I want to show every Month starting from first date of month rather then calendar showing previous or next month dates

```
 private void setStartDate() {

        calendar = LocalDate.now();
      //   calendarView.setSelectedDate(calendar);
        calendarView.getCurrentDate();


        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        Log.e("----", Calendar.DATE + "");

        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, c.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        calendarView.state().edit()
                .setMinimumDate(c)
                .commit();


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView
        android:id="@+id/smallView"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/calendar_size_small"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/calendar_size_small"
        app:mcv_showOtherDates="all"
 />
```

Just remove  `app:mcv_showOtherDates="all"` line from xml view